# Can you post fields from one form to another form using Webform in Drupal

Tags: forms, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I'm using Webform in Drupal to make this page: 
http://www.stuffusell.co.uk/drupal-7.4/collection-form

I want to build another child form on the home page and submit all fields (two or three in total) from that form to the corresponding fields on the fuller parent form on the link above.

I'm hoping to do this using Drupal, Webform and any suitable plugins. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to take a look at [Prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module.
It allows you to populate a form's fields passing the values in the url. You just have to create your home form with the good fields'names, form action to your webform and form method to "get".